# window.open not working in iFrame on Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a web page with an iFrame inside. The iFrame's src contains a Flash which contain `JavaScript:window.open`. It is working well on IE and Firefox but it is not firing the `window.open` on Chrome noting that if I open the Flash without iframe the `window.open` works on Chrome. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is not firing the click . you click without any event .

Comment: What's your HTML/JavaScript for this?

Comment: javascript:window.open('http://www.trainingLeb.com/Publications/Documents/AnnualReports/BankAudiAnnualReport2010.pdf','','left=85px; width=840px,height=600px,scrollbars=yes');  void(0);

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem in debugging a project. Using Chrome browser's Console to look at the Javascript error, you can see such a red text "Ignoring cross-frame javascript URL load requested by plugin." logged in the console. Therefore, the action appears not fired.

This must have been the security check in Chrome browser. The same configuration works in IE and FF, though.

However, if you put your Flash object in the only frame inside a browser window, the action will work in Chrome browser.